# Mismatched modulus value in RSAPubKey Elements

Tags: java, xml, xml-signature

I am trying to present a copy of my RSAKeyValue in the subjectConfirmationData of my SAML assertion.  The KeyInfo-KeyValue-RSAKeyValue-Modulus text that I am Base64 encoding does not match what the value is in the java xmlsignature-created KeyInfo that signs the assertion.

The assertion signature (this.rsaPubKey is of type RSAPublicKey):

```java
// now we can sign it
XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");            

// Create the DOMSignContext by specifying the signing informations: Private Key, Node to be signed, Where to insert the Signature.
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, assertionRoot, subject);
dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");

KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(this.rsaPubKey);
```

This is how I'm trying to create the KeyInfo in the subjectConfirmationData:

```java
// - ds:KeyInfo
Element keyInfo = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds:KeyInfo");
subjectConfirmationData.appendChild(keyInfo);
// - keyvalue
Element keyValue = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds:KeyValue");
keyInfo.appendChild(keyValue);
// - RSAKeyValue
Element rsaKeyValue = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds:RSAKeyValue");
keyValue.appendChild(rsaKeyValue);
// - modulus
Element modulusKey = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds:Modulus");
modulusKey.setTextContent(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsaPubKey.getModulus().toByteArray()));            
// exponent
Element exponentKey = securityDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#","ds:Exponent");
exponentKey.setTextContent(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsaPubKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray()));
rsaKeyValue.appendChild(exponentKey);
```

With this method, the resulting values in the  element do not match even closely.  What am I missing in my Base64 handling?

Comment: `BigInteger.toByteArray()` is _signed_ (two's complement) and when the value is an exact multiple of 8 bits, which RSA moduli usually are chosen to be, requires a leading zero byte for the sign, whereas `ds:cryptoBinary` is unsigned minimum-length with no leading zero byte(s). Try checking for and removing the zero byte, or (creating and) using a key whose modulus is an odd number of bits like 2046 bits instead of 2048.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, that was it, thank you so much.  If you'd like to re-post the comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  Again, thank you.